# Adding columns average and total

Tags: sql-server, average

I have this query below:

```
SELECT distinct COUNT(Status) AS [Transactions], sender AS [Supplier],
left(DATENAME(mm, Date_Reported), 3) AS Month, DATENAME(yyyy, Date_Reported) AS Year
 FROM TX
 where Date_Reported >= DATEADD(MONTH, -13, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
GROUP BY DATENAME(mm, Date_Reported), DATENAME(yyyy, Date_Reported), sender
ORDER BY sender, Year, Month DESC;
```

It gives me a table like below:

```
TX | Supplier | Month | Year
```

I would like to add two extra columns: the average of the last 13 months (ie May 17 - May 18) and also the total of the last 13 months, so the final table should look like this:

```
Supplier | May 17 | Jun 17 | Jul 17 ... | May 18 | Average | Total
```

Any ideas how I can make this possible with one large query?

Comment: That query doesn't compile, you are missing a `WHERE` predicate  after `FROM TX` .

Comment: Sorry edited now

Comment: OK - One more question: How are you going to present this data, SSRS/Power BI for example?  For example, if you were using SSRS I would concatentate the month and year into a new field and run a column grouping on it, then calculate the average and total in SSRS.

Comment: Yes ssrs- using visual studio to build the report

Comment: Please see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, amend your SQL query to do that concatenation in SSRS.  You can also do this in SSRS, but I prefer to do it in SQL. Also, I've removed your use of reserved words in your aliases (which is bad practice):

```
with cte
    (Transactions, Supplier, CalendarMonth, CalendarYear)
as (
       select distinct
              count([Status])
            , sender
            , left(datename(mm, Date_Reported), 3)
            , right(datename(yyyy, Date_Reported), 2)
       from TX
       where
           Date_Reported between
                                 dateadd(
                                       month
                                     , -13
                                     , cast(dateadd(month, DATEDIFF(month, -1, getdate()) - 2, 0) as date)
                                   )
                        and  cast(dateadd(ss, -1, DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, getdate()), 0)) as date)
       group by
           datename(mm, Date_Reported)
         , datename(yyyy, Date_Reported)
         , sender
   )
select Supplier
     , Transactions
     , CalendarMonth
     , CalendarYear
     , concat(CalendarMonth, ' ', CalendarYear) as ReportedMonth
from cte
order by
    CalendarYear
  , CalendarMonth asc;
```

In SSRS, you need use this query as your dataset source:

[image]

Then, you need to create a maxtrix as per the below design.  Note the column grouping on ReportedMonth:
[image]

The 'Average' and 'Total' columns should be created outside the column groupings. Below are the expressions for them, so you are calculating the averages/totals in SSRS:

[image]

[image]

Let me know how that goes.  The problem with an SQL solution is that you would have to use a `pivot` which means you would have to hard code the month values into the `pivot`, or generate the pivot using dynamic sql (not recommended).  This keeps the operations in SQL and SSRS much simpler and your report will dynamically stay up to date with the last 13 months.

Let me know how you get on.  Also, please tag this question with ssrs.

**PS:** Are you sure you want to use a rolling average of the past 13 months from `getdate()`? You'll get some pretty funky averages when you are partway through the month. Consider revising your sql to average over the previous 13 whole months.

Comment: That is amazing! Yes every new month I want the average to be over the new set of 13 months- not a rolling average

Comment: I've amended my answer to do that.  It's a `between` of the first day of the month that 13 months from last month and the last day of last month.

Comment: you are a lifesaver thank you so much for all your help :)